# Pandas: Cast datetime column as int

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a column of type datetime64 , which already keep in days

```
In [88]: print df.days.head()
0   756 days
1   262 days
2    72 days
3   173 days
4    12 days
Name: days, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to cast it as int64, I do the following:

```
df['days'] = df['days'].astype(int)/(24*3600*10**9)
```

this works, but curious is there a faster/better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [frequency conversion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion)

```
In [3]: s = Series(pd.to_timedelta(['756 days','2 days', '3 days 5 min']))

In [4]: s
Out[4]: 
0   756 days 00:00:00
1     2 days 00:00:00
2     3 days 00:05:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [5]: s.astype('timedelta64[D]')
Out[5]: 
0    756
1      2
2      3
dtype: float64

In [6]: s / np.timedelta64(1,'D') 
Out[6]: 
0    756.000000
1      2.000000
2      3.003472
dtype: float64
```